# InDesign: how to change the size of placed PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, file-placing

When I place PDF files in InDesign they will take up the whole page, so how can I make it smaller to allow space for the title on the top and the page number on the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two methods that you may find useful:
1) When you place the image, instead of simply clicking to drop the image onto the page, click and drag the frame to your desired size. By default, InDesign will lock the height and width to the original ratio while you are dragging.
2) Before placing the PDF, create a frame with your desired size and placement. **With that frame selected**, select File\Place... to select your PDF and click Open. It will insert the PDF into the frame. You may then need to fit the image to the frame.

[PROTIP:] There are some very convenient keyboard shortcuts that will be useful. The list of these commands can be found by right-clicking the graphic frame and selecting "Fitting".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to [place a file in InDesign](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/placing-graphics.html). After you select which file to place, you can:

- simply click on the page, which will place the file at 100% scale
- or, click AND hold AND drag, which scales the file while you're dragging